# Firebase Admin => Storage upload => How to find a download url?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase-storage, firebase-admin

I am using firebase Admin SDK for Nodejs. To successfully upload files. Now i need to use the upload response to determine a download url to be saved in a database... This was easy enough on the frontend but admin doesnt seem to document this.

```
import { getStorage } from "firebase-admin/storage";
import { UploadResponse } from "@google-cloud/storage";

async function upload(localFilePath) {
  const uploadResp: UploadResponse = await getStorage()
    .bucket()
    .upload(localFilePath);

  // how can i use UploadResponse to determine a public download url?
  return uploadResp;
}
```

how can i use UploadResponse to determine a public download url?

Comment: Admin SDK doesn't do download URLs.  That is for web and mobile clients only.  Backend SDKs have signed URLs.

Comment: yes. `getSignedUrl` worked

Answer (score 1):

`getSignedUrl` was my solution

```
import { getStorage } from "firebase-admin/storage";
import { UploadResponse } from "@google-cloud/storage";

async function upload(localFilePath) {
  const uploadResp: UploadResponse = await getStorage()
    .bucket()
    .upload(localFilePath);


  const downloadUrl = await uploadResp[0].getSignedUrl({
    action: "read",
    expires: "03-09-2491",
  });
  return downloadUrl;
}
```

**Edit**
This also works

```
const downloadUrl = `https://storage.googleapis.com/${bucket}/${location}`;
```